# Condition of f to be Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Which of the following statements is/are true?

(a)Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f(t)>0$ for all $t>0$, then $f$ is continuous.

(b) Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x+y)=f(x) f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(c) Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $x=0$ and such that $f(x)+f(x / 2)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

(d) None of the above

I have been able to prove that (b), and (c) are correct but I am stuck with option (a).
The answer says it's true. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a good overview of facts about the Cauchy functional equation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/42969

Comment: @Sayantan, look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656500/if-f0-infty-to-0-infty-and-fxy-fxfy-then-prove-that-fx-ax/1656570#1656570